# Render multiple views within a single request

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, tiles

I'm trying to return multiple views within a single request, returning them all in a JSON string.

Example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "my-request")
public void myRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
{
    Map<String,Object> model1 = new Hashtable<String,Object>();
    model1.put(...);
    ModelAndView modelAndView1 = new ModelAndView("path/to/view1", model1);
    // Render modelAndView1 in some way, in order to obtain the rendered HTML as a String

    Map<String,Object> model2 = new Hashtable<String,Object>();
    model2.put(...);
    ModelAndView modelAndView2 = new ModelAndView("path/to/view2", model2);
    // Render modelAndView2 in some way, in order to obtain the rendered HTML as a String

    // Now write a JSON String to the HttpServletResponse containing both the rendered views (strings).
    // (this is not part of my problem, I'm able to do it as long as I have the two strings)
}
```

I'm using Spring MVC with Tiles 2.

Can anyone help me?

**Update 1** - View names are resolved using a `ViewResolver`:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

**Update 2** - I've created a [github repository](https://github.com/MintTwist/ViewResolver-test) containing a very small example reproducing the problem.

Comment: So in fact you dont want to show up any views, but pass a String to your client?

Comment: The strings I'm speaking about are the rendered HTML as strings (changed the original question accordingly)

Comment: If your using tiles combine to tile views into a single composite view and redirect to the name of the it.

Comment: I don't want to use a single composite view, I need the views to stay separate. The JSON response will be managed by JavaScript that will put a view here and a view there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE:** There are some approaches for solving your issue. I'd try this one, but maybe there are cleaner ways.

```
@Component
public class JsonMultipleViewFactory {

    @Autowired private List<ViewResolver> viewResolverList;

    public View getView(List<ModelAndView> mavList) {
        for (ModelAndView mav : mavList) {
            if (mav.getView()==null) {
                mav.setView(resolve(mav.getViewName()));
            }
        }
        return new JsonMultipleView(mavList);
    }

    private View resolve(String viewName) {
        for (ViewResolver vr : viewResolverList) {
            View view = vr.resolve(viewName, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
            if (view!=null) {
                return view;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class JsonMultipleView implements View {

    private final List<ModelAndView> mavList;

    public JsonMultipleView(List<ModelAndView> mavList) {
        this.mavList = mavList;
    }

    public String getContentType() { 
        return "application/json"; 
    }

    public void render(Map<String,?> model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Json json = new Json(); // You can use several Json libraries here
        for (ModelAndView mav : mavList) {
            MockHttpServletResponse mockResponse = new MockHttpServletResponse();
            mav.getView().render(mav.getModel(), request, mockResponse);
            json.add(mav.getViewName(), mockResponse.getContentAsString());
        }
        json.write(response.getOutputStream());
        response.getOutputStream().close();
    }
}
```

And can be used like this:

```
@Autowired private JsonMultipleViewFactory jsonMultipleViewFactory;

@RequestMapping(value = "my-request")
public View myRequest() {
    ...
    List<ModelAndView> mavList = new ArrayList<ModelAndView>();
    mavList.add(modelAndView1);
    mavList.add(modelAndView2);
    return jsonMultipleViewFactory.getView(mavList);
}
```

Comment: Hang on. I get a `NullPointerException` because `mav.getView()` returns null, do you know why? The `ModelAndView`s are created exactly as in my example. Thanks!

Comment: From the `getView()` doc: "Return the View object, or null if we are using a view name to be resolved by the DispatcherServlet via a ViewResolver."... How can I avoid this?

Comment: Thank you @sinuhepop - I thought to do something similar. Your solution throws an exception: "org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver] found for dependency [collection of org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver]". I've got two servlets and they both contain a `ViewResolver` in their `*-servlet.xml` file. IntelliJ IDEA is not giving any warning when typing the `@Autowiring`, while it usually gives them when autowiring beans that don't exist...

Comment: How/where are you loading your JsonMultipleViewFactory bean? If via XML, in what file? Are you sure the Spring context that is being loaded into one of the Web application contexts you're creating for your two servlets, where the ViewResolver beans are created? Also, why do you have two servlets each with its own *-servlet.xml file? That seems unusual.

Comment: Hello @sdouglass, sorry for late reply. The `JsonMultipleViewFactory` is autowired in the controller. I have a servlet for normal requests, where I configure tiles, map static resources (CSS/images/scripts etc.) and configure the view resolver with "/WEB-INF/jsp/" as prefix and ".jsp" as suffix. Then I have another servlet for ajax requests, where the only thing I configure is the view resolver with "/WEB-INF/tiles/" as prefix and ".jsp" as suffix. I really don't understand why the `ViewResolver` doesn't get autowired..

Comment: Anyway, having multiple servlets is not the problem. Please see my original question, I added the details to a github repository containing a very small example reproducing the problem (using a single servlet). Please help! Thanks.

Comment: Hi again. In your example, `JsonMultipleViewFactory` is discovered through component scanning by parent context (`applicationContext.xml`). `InternalResourceViewResolver` is defined in child context (`test-servlet.xml`). So, is normal that parent context can't see beans defined in child context. This is the reason why you get a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`. Try to put all this beans in the same context.

Comment: I don't understand what I am supposed to put in the applicationContext.xml and what in the xxx-servlet.xml. To me they look very similar and I cannot make a distinction between them... I noticed that the view resolver works only if I put it in the xxx-servlet.xml file. So I tried to move all the beans into this file (I have a lot of beans that are not autowired). The only problem is that, for some reason, if I do that the controllers are no longer able to autowire the classes annotated with `@Service`, but only the ones annotated with `@Repository`. Any help very appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Typically `applicationContext.xml` contains "core" beans and configuration and `xxx-servlet.xml` only the view part. But I think that's usually better to have only one context so you can put all in `applicationContext.xml` and delete `xxx-servlet.xml` file. You must configure your `DispatcherServlet` in `web.xml` with `<init-param><param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name><param-value></param-value></init-param>`.

Comment: Thank you, @sinuhepop. I tried to do that but I now get "ERROR org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException - failed to lazily initialize a collection of role my.package.Class, no session or session was closed". Seems like the filter `OpenSessionInViewFilter` doesn't work when the `ViewResolver` is not configured in the xxx-servlet.xml file... Can you help? Thank you so much for the help so far.

Comment: I think this is a different problem and probably has nothing to do with your initial issue. Search in SO for it, it's very common and there are a couple of solutions.