# Autowire ViewResolver in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired

For some reason I'm not able to Autowire the `ViewResolver`:

```
@Component
public class JsonMultipleViewFactory
{
    @Autowired
    private ViewResolver viewResolver;

    // ...
}
```

viewResolver is `null`.

The class `JsonMultipleViewFactory` is Autowired in a spring controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController
{
    @Autowired
    private JsonMultipleViewFactory jsonMultipleViewFactory;

    // ...
}
```

I've created a [github repository](https://github.com/MintTwist/ViewResolver-test) containing a very small example reproducing the problem.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: `ViewResolver` is registered as bean ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Render multiple views within a single request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705293/render-multiple-views-within-a-single-request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705293/render-multiple-views-within-a-single-request), with no answer:

> In your example, `JsonMultipleViewFactory` is discovered through
>   component scanning by parent context (`applicationContext.xml`).
>   `InternalResourceViewResolver` is defined in child context
>   (`test-servlet.xml`). So, is normal that parent context can't see beans
>   defined in child context. This is the reason why you get a
>   `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`. Try to put all this beans in the same
>   context.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you didn't register your view resolver as a spring bean, you need to add to the application context something like :

```
<bean class="package.full.name.ViewResolver" />
```